# Display text on screen that matches @allure.title('...') text for display during video recording of pytesting

Tags: python, windows, pytest, allure

We are using pytest and Allure for testing our software with great results. Part of our setup is video recording of the GUI testing. It would be very useful to display text of which test is currently being ran on the screen. Does any know if there is a way to display the @allure.title('...') as a title bar on the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebDriver [execute_script](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method with [document.title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) command.

```
def test_some_case():
    case_title = 'Some Title'
    allure.dynamic.title(case_title)
    driver.execute_script('document.title = arguments[0];', case_title)

    some_checks()
```